# Why am I getting an Assertion Error in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, assertion

I am testing a function in Python. This is the function I wrote.

```
def hypotenuse(a, b):
   math.sqrt(a**2 + b**2)
```

I used this test case.

```
def test_hypotenuse_1(self):
   self.assertEqual(funcs.hypotenuse, 3, 4)
```

This assertion error came up.

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_hypotenuse_1 (__main__.TestCases)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "funcs_tests.py", line 27, in test_hypotenuse_1
    self.assertEqual(funcs.hypotenuse, 3, 4)
AssertionError: <function hypotenuse at 0x7f397f2d79d8> != 3 : 4
```

What did I do wrong? Sorry if this is a basic question I am a first-time coder.

Comment: you probably have to _call_ `funcs.hypotenuse`. And you also have to _return_ something from `hypothenuse`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the function, and then specify what the result of that call is supposed to be equal to

```
def test_hypotenuse_1(self):
    self.assertEqual(funcs.hypotenuse(3, 4), 5)
```

This asserts that the hypotenuse of a triangle with sides 3 and 4 is equal to 5.

Your test will still fail because `hypotenuse()` doesn't return the result. It needs to be:

```
def hypotenuse(a, b):
    return math.sqrt(a**2 + b**2)
```

Note that you should generally not use equality testing for a mathematical function like this. It uses floating point arithmetic, which can have roundoff error. You can use the [`assertAlmostEqual()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertAlmostEqual) function for this.